# How to create dropdown from existing data?

Tags: excel, dropdown

One of my worksheets (Sites) contains a list of sites.

Column B contains the sites unique ID, Column C contains the site type.
This is an example, the real data will have many more entries.
Eg:

```
Column B     Column C
1234-56789   NW175
5468-58754   SW124
8787-97979   PO962
9247-75204   NW116
1458-56155   NW120
7486-89251   KA960
975-983044   PO630
```

I'd like to be able to present a dropdown list in cell A5 on worksheet 1 (Home) containing only entries starting with NW.

I'd like the list to appear as:

```
NW175 - 1234-56789   
NW116 - 9247-75204   
NW120 - 1458-56155
```

Is there any way to do this *without* using macros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Excel 365 then you can use the new FILTER-Function.
Also I would propose that you use a table to define your site-configuration.

There you add a new column, e.g. Full name and apply the formula to concatenate both values.

Then the new FILTER-function comes into play - see my screenshot - you have to use the formula `=FILTER(tblSiteInfo[Full name];LEFT(tblSiteInfo[Site Type];2) = "NW")` --> the filtered result spills down as a new list

Next step: define a name for the cell (and only the cell with the formula) and apply a # at the end of the name-address.

You can then use this name for your validation list.

[image]

Benefit of this solution: if you add more sites to the configuration table the validation list will update automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply.. I don't have the option of creating a new column, unless that can be done on a new worksheets that I can hide ?

Comment: Yes - you can put everything on a hidden sheet. Alternativly you can put the concatenation into the FILTER-Formula (`=FILTER(tblSiteInfo[Site Type] & " - " & tblSiteInfo[Unique ID];LEFT(tblSiteInfo[Site Type];2) = "NW")`)

Comment: By the way: There is a bug/feature/ :-/ due to which it is not possible to set FILTER-formula within the names dialog and then use this name for the validation list. That's why it is necessary to go this way

Comment: I'm doing something wrong here. My columns not have names so I've changed the filter to be ` =FILTER(Sites[B] & " - " & Sites[C];LEFT(Sites[C];2) = "NW")`  I've tried to add this to a cell on a new worksheet but I get an error. 'There is a problem with this formula'  Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you insert a table for your configuration (put your cursor anywhere in the list > Ribbon > Insert > table)? You can identify a table by the caret at the bottom right corner (see my screenshot).  If you haven't worked with tables - look here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c

Comment: I don't have a table, just two columns. I'd pre not to change the layout if possible.

Comment: Then you have to use the classic way to reference the columns: `=FILTER( C:C & " - " & B:B; LEFT(C:C;2) = "NW")`

Comment: Thanks for you help with this, but it still throws the error and highlights the Second B. It doesn't seem to like the `;`  I'll try ','

Comment: Sorted :) `=FILTER( Sites!C:C & " - " & Sites!B:B, LEFT(Sites!C:C, 2) = "NW")` entered into a cell on my hidden worksheet.

Comment: Sorry - German Excel uses semicolon - I forgot to clean this up

Answer (score 0):

To concat strings with cell variables use `&` operator. According to your example paste this `=C2&" - "&B2` to column D `for example D2` and pull down to apply rest of rows below.

For creating a dropdown menu from concatenated data follow these steps.

1 - Select the cell where you want to create dropdown list

2 - Go to `Data` tab

3 - Click to `Data Validation`

4 - Select `List` from `Allow` dropdown

5 - Click `Source` and mark column D for example `=$D$2:$D$8`

6 - Click `Ok`

Comment: Thanks, will this filter the results so just entries starting `NW` will be shown ?